# gvim mapping keys to ex commands while in visual mode?

Tags: vim, gvim, keymap, visual-mode

So in gvim, after I press

```
<Shift> + v
```

it goes into visual mode. I normally have an ex command set for the letting 'm'. When I go into visual mode and then hit 'm' it says

```
No range allowed
```

How do I make it so that when I push 'm' in visual mode, it does

```
:ya +
```

Basically, I want it so that after I highlight something in visual mode, if I click 'm', it copies it to my clipboard so that I can paste it on stuff outside of gvim.

Comment: The most important part of your question is missing: your custom command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (yanking to clipboard) would be a simple

```
xnoremap m :ya +<CR>
```

Without your mapping, I can't say where that `No range allowed` comes from. The `:`, when pressed in visual mode, automatically inserts the `:'<,'>` visual range, and the `:yank` command takes a range, so all works out well. On the other hand, should you have a command that doesn't take a range you'd have to clear it via `:<C-u>command ...`.

Note: I used `:xmap` instead of `:vmap` because in *select mode*, printable letters should replace the selection, not invoke a mapping.